# ReGEX to select just the TVShow name

Tags: php, regex

I want my PHP script to search for files in a folder and I want ReGEX to get just the main filename from it.

The files are TVShows with fansub group etc. But I just need the show name.

```
[Final8]Nazo no Kanojo X 01-13 + OVA (BD 10-bit 1920x1080 x264 FLAC)  
[Final8]Nazo no Kanojo X 01-13 + OVA (BD 10-bit 1280x720 x264 AAC)  
[HorribleSubs] OreShura - 05 [1080p].mkv  
[HorribleSubs] OreShura - 05 [720p].mkv  
[Hatsuyuki]_Naruto_Shippuuden_-_298_[720p][3FF2ABFE].mp4  
[Commie] Mondaiji-tachi ga Isekai kara Kuru Sou Desu yo - 04 [18B50CAF].mkv  
[FFF] Maoyuu Maou Yuusha - 05 [E84974F0].mkv  
[Commie] Chihayafuru 2 - 04 [AB85B68E].mkv  
[gg]_Sasami-san@Ganbaranai_-_04_[4D5B88AF].mkv  
[Nutbladder] JoJo's Bizarre Adventure - 17  
[UTW]_Shinsekai_Yori_-_18_[h264-720p][FAC060C0].mkv
```

I want to remove the Fansub name in the [ ] brackets and all the rest part of the filename like episode number and etc etc. 
I want just main filename like Nazo no Kanojo, OreShura, Naruto_Shippuuden (or better Naruto Shippuuden), etc.

I tried making a REGEX myself but it didn't go well, any help would be appreciated in this and if possible, please see if you can also comment what part of ReGEX does what, as that way I can learn as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex will get you the title, but it won't look perfect. It will still have any dashes and underscores that appear in the name.

```
(?<=])[^\.][\D]+
```

Here's a working example using some of the strings you provided: http://fiddle.re/hz9b

You could then do a second pass to remove any of those unwanted characters.

Comment: Tried it at RegExr, it seems to be working but 2 problems:  
As you just said, the file name still has dashes and underscore, if possible, can it be removed in same regex ? or else I will just use str_replace in php somehow  
Second problem is, its also selecting the CRC code in the brackets if it starts with alphabets  
Check here [link](http://regexr.com?33kq9)  

PS: How do you add a linebreak in comments ? two spaces at end of line and pressing shift+enter not working

Comment: thanks for all the help, just got everything worked out after hit and try executions, final ReGex I used is  
`(?<=])[^\.][\D]+[^\d\s_-]{4}`  
And had to use a few more php functions to strip whitespaces and underscores but all sorted now, really super thanks for the help..... if you dont mind, can you also explain what each part of the ReGex you suggested does/will do ? I only got like 70% of it understood

Comment: Yea, sure! Check out this site, it's pretty useful. http://www.regex101.com/r/lR2sQ5